# RMM configuration with SAP, dynamic Sender Profiles and Email to Case?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email2case, sap, reply-mail-management

For our SFMC configuration we are using multiple Sender Profiles which should allow for the customers to reply, and have all their replies result in a case created in SF. One of the Sender Profiles is a dynamic one, configured using a content block which selects a set of From Addres+Reply To Address based on customer data in the Sending Data Extension.
Email to Case is already set up and is working for one@company.com, two@company.com, three@company.com addresses which are configured to forward to SF specific addresses which handle case creation. This has been tested and works well.

We have requested the SAP to handle sending from Marketing Cloud. Our SAP subdomain is @communication.company.com. As we have multiple Sender Profiles with different Reply To addresses, including the dynamic one, we have set up RMM independently for all of them - using the 'Custom Reply Mail Management Settings' option in the Sender Profile configuration. For example we have set up the From Address to be one@communication.company.com, checked 'Use custom settings below' in RMM settings and put one@company.com for reply forwarding in 'Use Specified Information' (this is just one option from the dynamic sender profile, the actual values in the settings are variables from a content block).

We have tested this setup and it leads to cases being created in SF when the customer replies, but not correctly linked to the contact as the from Addresses of the customer in SF becomes customer@mail.com@communication.company.com. Curiously, this issue occurs for all but one of our addresses, for which the cases do link properly and the from address of the customer remains customer@mail.com.

Is our setup correct? Or should we be using one@reply.company.com, two@reply.company.com etc addresses in replyTo? We tested this approach and it did not work, but we are wondering if that's due to some DNS changes we have missed but should have done. Does our existing set up has any impact on deliverability + the way the emails are forwarded?

Answer (score 2):

The problem you describe is caused by so-called [DMARC Forward Reply Rewrite](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_dmarc_fwd_reply_rewrite.htm&type=5) feature in Marketing Cloud.

You want to raise a support case at Salesforce to ask them to disable it for the business units where you require the replies to arrive to Service Cloud. This will prevent the email address from being changed, and the cases will be correctly linked to the appropriate contact.

Comment: Thanks, I've read about it - will it not impact the deliverability of forwarded messages though? Reading the help section on the DMARC Forward Reply Rewrite and other stackexchange posts around it, it looks like it could cause issues when a customer is replying from a yahoo.com mailbox for example. Could that lead to a case being lost? Or does this issue not apply here? Note - we are forwarding to company emails first, and they are configured to forward to SF inboxes (was like this in old setup). I guess we could also change that to forward to SF inboxes immediately from RMM.

Comment: I haven't seen cases where there is an impact on deliverability, no. And I support the idea of forwarding directly to SF.